# openpyxl save does not work

Tags: excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

I create an excel workbook:

```
wb = Workbook()
```

create and populate some worksheets:

```
active_sheet = wb.copy_worksheet(temp_sheet)
active_sheet.title = 'Availabilty'
for i in range(len(np_S_Availability)):
    for j in range(len(np_S_Availability[0])):
        active_sheet.cell(column=j+2, row=i+2, value=np_S_Availability[i, j])
```

and then save it:

```
wb.save(destinf)
```

But at this point it just hangs.  No response, no error messages that I can detect.  Any ideas perhaps?

Paul

Comment: How big is your array? You should be able to watch the Python process to see if it's still active. It's unlikely to hang.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think the take home here is to use the `write_only=True` option.  These are big arrays resulting in workbooks in excess of 10MB.  I have changed the code to allow for this and now all works fine.  Thanks.

Comment: I can't save files like this. Help please? Error is:
`I/O Operation on closed file`